# Ignore Twitter Gem Exceptions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, rubygems, rescue

how do I rescue and ignore the exceptions thrown by twitter gem? 
what I want is this

```
begin
Twitter.update(@tweet)
rescue Twitter::Error
 // continue action 1 
else 
 // continue action 1
end
```

is there a better way of doing this so I don't duplicate the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about handling the error, try this:

```
Twitter.update(@tweet) rescue Twitter::Error
# continue action 1
```